# Connecting cassandra to python on pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, pycharm

I am new to Cassandra and trying to connect it to python. I use pycharm as my IDE and am trying to connect to a cassandra database on a different server on Pycharm. I tried using datastax but I am reaching several roadblocks.

```
import cql
con= cql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=9160,keyspace="testKS")
```

This above is the code I have tried but it leads on several errors

Comment: you'll find more people willing to help if you post the code you've tried so far

Comment: First, it's not a pycharm related issue. Second, If it's on another host, for sure the IP address os not 127.0.0.1. maybe 172.x.x.x

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which version of Cassandra you're on, but the **newer versions now disable Thrift on port 9160 by default**, because the Thrift protocol has been deprecated.

Which driver are you trying to use?  If you're following an example, you're probably trying to use a driver that's *also* been deprecated, due to its dependence on the Thrift model.

You will have much more success using the [DataStax Python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) for Cassandra.  It installs easily via pip (`sudo pip install cassandra-driver`) and the [getting started guide](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html) can get you on the correct path.